# Newly created Azure elastic job agent does not appear in the Azure portal resource listing

Tags: azure-sql-database

What can I do to make it appear again?

I created an elastic job agent which appeared to be created as expected. The deployment log shows the deployment as succesful but it's link
I did not delete or change the agent afterwards.

The agent functions fine and continues to function although very slowly. A job doing little more than calling a single stored procedure takes 5 minutes to start after running an EXEC jobs.sp_start_job command for immediate execution. I am not sure if this is related to the issue or just low performance / low cycle frequency of the agent.

Although the agent is not visible in the resource list on the Azure portal, it seems to exist in the background. Azure won't let me create a new agent and throws me a conflict error with the existing agent. Deleting the database is not possible either because of active job agent linked to the db.

The agent DB I am using is a classic standard S0 tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some issues on Azure portal reported by Azure customers and confirmed [here](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport/status/1219281092034719744) by Azure Support around 9 hours ago around the same time when you created this thread.It took them one hour to resolve the issue for most regions.

On Nordic areas of Europe there still issues about 3 hours ago. For more information, please visit this [URL](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status/history/).

Comment: Realized that I never replied on your answer. The post you referred to seemed related indeed and the issue dissapeared shortly after. Thx!